# Scope all instances of an object with two depth relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope

Sorry for the title I have some difficulties to explain my issue, and even more in english.

My use case is that:

I have one user who has_many teams, each team own one game.

I would like add a method (a scope I believe) in my model user who gets me all the games who are related with the user. I thought something like that:

```
scope :games, includes({:teams => [:game]})
```

This line don't work for some reason i don't know yet.
But if I succeed to do that I will get all the teams and all the games.

Whereas I would like only an array with the games.

I search the more elegant way to do that.
Thanks for reading :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Rails 4, then all scopes must be wrapped in lambdas.

```
scope :games, -> { includes({:teams => [:game]}) }
```